# How to launch video icon in camera

Tags: android, shell, c#-2.0, xamarin.android

I am trying to launch an app through `adb` in my android phone. I have tried `adb getevent`.

But it dumps so many events. How can I make out which one I need? Is there any other way I can launch the app? I am looking to launch the video portion of the camera.
I was able to launch camera thru adb as:

`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.camera/.CameraEntry`.

The camcorder icon is next to snap icon in camera. I was able to control snap icon through
`input keyevent 23. But unable to figure out how to launch video which is next to snap icon.

Comment: are you using Mono for Android?  If so, you should really include that (as well as android) in your tags/description, otherwise people aren't going to have any idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Can you please stop posting [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458843/how-to-launch-an-app-thru-adb-in-android) within a space of the last hour?